# C++ OpenGL I can't see a cube on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I can't see a cube on the screen.I located it with glTranslatef. I got it to stop somewhere with LoadIdentity. I wanted to get a camera by changing the Matrix Modes, but the cube does not appear.

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cstdio>

int width = 1280;
int height = 720;

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1, -1, -1,   -1, -1,  1,   -1,  1,  1,   -1,  1, -1,
    1, -1, -1,    1, -1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1,  1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1,   -1, -1,  1,    1, -1,  1,    1, -1, -1,
    -1,  1, -1,   -1,  1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1,  1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1,   -1,  1, -1,    1,  1, -1,    1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1,  1,   -1,  1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1, -1,  1
};

GLfloat colors[] =
{
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0
};

void keyboard(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void drawCube() {

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

}


int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "C++ OpenGL Test Area", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyboard);


    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    
    


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        /* Render here */
        glClearColor(0.0, 192/256, 1, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();


        gluLookAt(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glTranslatef(0, 0, 5);
        drawCube();


        glFlush();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it was because I couldn't draw the cube. I checked the codes again, but there is no problem drawing the cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube is not in the viewing volume. If you do not specify a projection matrix, the viewing volume is a unique cube around the camera position, aligned along the line of sight. Any geometry that is not in the viewing volume is clipped. You must set up a projection matrix. The projection matrix defines the volume in the scene that is projected onto the viewport. An orthographic projection matrix can be set with [`glOrtho`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). A perspective projection matrix can be set with [`glFrustum`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml) or [`gluPerspective`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). The perspective projection matrix defines a [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). e.g.:

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
float aspect = (float)width / (float)height;
gluPerspective(90.0, aspect, 0.1, 10.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

drawCube();
```